# How to change Akismet commenter privacy notice?

Tags: hooks, comment-form, privacy, akismet

I read [the supposed explanation posted on their blog](https://blog.akismet.com/2018/06/07/customisation-options-for-the-akismet-front-end-privacy-notice/), and came away unenlightened.

The following site-specific plugin does nothing (I have enabled it):

```php
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Akismet Better Privacy Notice
Description: Inform users about what's actually happening with their data
*/

apply_filters(
    'akismet_comment_form_privacy_notice_markup',
    '<p class="akismet_comment_form_privacy_notice">' .
    'Warning: This site uses Akismet to filter spam.' .
    ' Until or unless I can find a suitable replacement anti-spam solution, this means that' .
    ' (per their <a href="%s" target="_blank">indemnification document</a>)' .
    ' <strong>all commenters\' IP addresses will be sent to Automattic, Inc.</strong>,' .
    ' who may choose to share such with 3rd parties.' .
    '<br />If this is unacceptable to you,' .
    ' I highly recommend using an anonymous proxy or public Wi-Fi connection' .
    ' when commenting.' .
    '</p>'
);

?>
```

How can I change this privacy message?

Comment: I am aware that this notice might not technically fulfill the GDPR. That is **not an issue**, as my jurisdiction of residence isn't under that. I am trying to inform visitors, not satisfy lawyers.

Comment: That's not how filters work, the second parameter must be the name of a function to call that returns the new/filtered value, not the new value itself.

Answer (score -1):

Aha, I finally got it working:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Akismet Better Privacy Notice
Description: Inform users about what's actually happening with their data
*/

add_filter (
    'akismet_comment_form_privacy_notice_markup', 'better_display_comment_form_privacy_notice'
);

function better_display_comment_form_privacy_notice() {
    echo sprintf(
        '<p class="akismet_comment_form_privacy_notice">' .
        'Warning: This site uses Akismet to filter spam.' .
        ' Until or unless I can find a suitable replacement anti-spam solution, this means that' .
        ' (per their <a href="%s" target="_blank">indemnification document</a>)' .
        ' <strong>all commenters\' IP addresses will be sent to Automattic, Inc.</strong>,' .
        ' who may choose to share such with 3rd parties.' .
        '<br />If this is unacceptable to you,' .
        ' I highly recommend using an anonymous proxy or public Wi-Fi connection' .
        ' when commenting.' .
        '</p>' ,
        'https://akismet.com/privacy/'
    );
}

?>
```

Comment: note that this bypasses the filter and could be causing issues you don't know about. Filters always return a value, but your filter does not return a value, resulting in an empty value. You need to return it, not `echo` it. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/